# Joomla query with multiple where

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla

I'm trying to get results from the database but my sql it's not very good.

I'm on joomla3 and what I want to achieve is to have a list of articles from multiple categories and I'd like to order the results of all the articles by date (not by category) but the 'where' clause seem not to be working.

These the querys I've tried so far but no one is working:

```
$query->select('id, title, introtext, created, created_by, images, urls');
$query->from('#__content');

//1st 'where' try
$query->where('catid=12'OR' catid=11'OR' catid=10');

//2nd 'where' try
$query->where('catid=12');
$query->OR('catid=11');
$query->OR('catid=10');

//3rd 'where' try
$query->where('catid = 11', 'OR')
->where('catid = 12');

$query->order('id DESC');
```

Any suggestion of what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your Joomla format of query writing

```
$query->select('id, title, introtext, created, created_by, images, urls'); 
$query->from('#__content');
$query->where('catid IN (10, 11, 12)'); //quotes fixed
$query->order('id DESC'); 

$db->setQuery($query);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer and sorry for the mess in my code, I've edited it now.
I've tried this code but it doesn't work:
$query->select('id, title, introtext, created, created_by, images, urls');
$query->from('#__content');
$query->where catid IN ( 10, 11, 12 );
$query->order('id DESC');
$db->setQuery($query);

Comment: are we missing single quotes on `$query->where catid IN ( 10, 11, 12 );` Before executing `$db->setQuery($query);` can we print the query in browser

Comment: I've tried this:$query->where catid IN (' 10',' 11',' 12 ');   and this:  $query->where catid IN (' 10, 11, 12 ');   but it say syntax error on both.